# How to save a input string in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream wysla;
  wysla.open("wysla.txt", ios::app);
  int kaput;
  string s1,s2;
  cout<<"Please select from the List below"<<endl;
  cout<<"1.New entry"<<endl;
  cout<<"2.View Previous Entries"<<endl;
  cout<<"3.Delete an entry"<<endl;
  cin>>kaput;
  switch (kaput)
  {
    case 1:

      cout<<"Dear diary,"<<endl;
      getline(cin,s1);
      wysla<<s1;
      wysla.close();

      break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In this code I have tried to save a string of characters but it is not possible e.g,.. when I use getline nothing is saved on the text file when I use cin only the first word is saved. I would like to save the whole entry what do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after `cin >> kaput;` to remove `\n` from buffer.

```
cin >> kaput;
cin.ignore();
```

> Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and
>   including delim.

As the comment, you'd better to use

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: I would use `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');` because if the user had input 4 and then two spaces and then enter, this wouldn't work

Comment: good idea but in my main program wen i use                                 cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');   it brings up some errors though the first answer works

Comment: @Wysla: If think to solve those errors you should `#include <limits>` because of `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to insert a `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> kaput` to read the newline character at the end of the first input. Otherwise `getline` sees this newline as the first character, consumes it and ends reading.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the number, number will be read into `kaput` variable, but `'\n'` character will still be in the buffer, which will be read by `getline`). To resolve this issue you need to call `cin.ignore()` to remove newline character from the `stdin` buffer

Answer (score 0):

This can work :

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       string firstname;
       ofstream name;
       name.open("name");
       cout<<"Name? "<<endl;
       cin>>firstname;
       name<<firstname;
       name.close();
    }
```